# Image viewer for renaming the current image

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, image-viewers

I have a set of images with the date printed on them and I was wondering if anyone knows about an image viewer with the possibility of renaming while looking at the image, to make it faster and to avoid having to open the image and then rename at the file list in the folder.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Geeqie Image Viewer will do this.

http://geeqie.sourceforge.net/

```
apt-get install geeqie
```

or

http://sourcedigit.com/19324-19324/

Comment: geeqie does that very well. You may configure keyboard shortcuts in the settings to make it even faster e.g. by pressing 'r' only, a rename dialogue opens.

Answer (score 1):

XnView Multi Platform will let you rename images "on the fly".  Simply click on the file name in the thumbnail view and change the name.

https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/

Comment: Also works in single-pic -mode and full-screen-mode, just hit `F2`.

Answer (score 0):

`qiv` supports custom operations on a file. You could e.g. use the script listed below. You'd have to save it is `qiv-command` somewhere on your path,
and then you could rename the file by pressing `0`, and give the file a different prefix by pressing '1'.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

case "$1" in
    0)
        # Rename file
        DIR="$(dirname $2)"
        FILE="$(basename $2)"
        NEW_FILE_NAME=$(zenity --title="Rename file" --entry --text="Rename file '$2'" --entry-text="$FILE" 2> /dev/null)
        if test -n "$NEW_FILE_NAME" && test "$DIR/$NEW_FILE_NAME" != "$2"; then
            echo "NEWNAME=$DIR/$NEW_FILE_NAME"
            mv -i "$2" "$DIR/$NEW_FILE_NAME"
        else
            echo "file not renamed"
        fi
        ;;
    1)
        # Rename file with prefix
        PREFIX=$(zenity --title="Prefix file" --entry --text="Give prefix to file '$2'" --entry-text="" 2> /dev/null)
        if test -n "$PREFIX"; then
            DIR="$(dirname $2)"
            FILE="$(basename $2)"
            echo "NEWNAME=$DIR/$PREFIX-$FILE"
            mv -i "$2" "$DIR/$PREFIX-$FILE"
        else
            echo "file not renamed"
        fi
    ;;
    *)
        echo "ERROR: Please provide 0 or 1 as first option"
        ;;
esac
```