# What photo and video manager software?

Tags: video, photo

I just want to quickly preview and rename my photos and videos, but I can't find any software that does it outside of the Gnome or KDE worlds.

Is there any?

Comment: I think it's better to ask two questions, one for image viewer, another for video. For image viewer you may check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966175/image-viewer-for-renaming-while-watching-the-image

Comment: To (batch) rename photos based on EXIF information see https://askubuntu.com/questions/346011/how-to-rename-multiple-photos-and-videos-based-on-exif-data - to view photos see https://askubuntu.com/questions/237310/what-fast-image-viewers-are-available-for-ubuntu and https://askubuntu.com/questions/97695/is-there-a-lightweight-tool-to-crop-images-quickly. What do you mean by outside of GNOME or KDE? What would be wrong with it?

Comment: The point is, video and photo are completely mixed, nowadays.  I am using xmonad as window manager and don't know much outside a very limited world of web browsers and text editors. It looks like every major desktop environment has a file browser that integrates video and photo  management, but what about  software build just for that purpose?

Comment: I'm also looking. GCstar - no preview. Banshee - crashes on import attempt. Others - obsolete, not working. :/